# How to convert IEnumerable<MySpecificEnumType> to generic IEnumerable<Enum> in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I have a user control that uses a combobox with its source being bound to an `IEnumerable` of type `Enum` (I have several different types of user defined enums to be used in the user control, so use the generic `IEnumerable<Enum>` in the backing code of my user control). However, when I attempt to create the `IEnumerable` list in the backing code of the item using the user control, I can't convert my `IEnumerable` of my own enum type to the generic Enum `IEnumerable`.

I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type `MyEnumType[]` to type `System.Enum[]`

when I attempt to convert to `Enum[]`.

The code causing this error is:

```
public IEnumerable<Enum> MyEnums { get { return (Enum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MySpecificEnumType)); } }
```

How should I convert from a list of my enum type to a list of the generic `Enum` type? Or should I be using a different type of `IEnumerable` in the backing code of my user control?

Comment: It's a bad idea. Don't use *generic* `IEnumerable<T>` inside user control. Use non-generic `IEnumerable` instead as items source for `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to get `IEnumerable<Enum>`, you can use [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MySpecificEnumType)).Cast<Enum>();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `...Cast<IEnumerable<Enum>>();`?

Comment: @Zack No, you just specify the type of the element.